# Bi-linear Interpolation for Radiosity

Tags: opengl

I have developed an OpenGL project using the old GL_QUADS rendering, not using Shaders.

I want to average the colours of mine radiosity solution. I have a number of patches per face. What I did:

I average the colours of the adjacent patches within a face. I got good results but still getting some mach band effect.

Ill try to explain what I did:

```
//  ___________________ 
// |v3     v2|v3     v2|
// |         |         |
// |         |         |
// |    2    |    3    | 
// |         |         |
// |v0_____v1|v0_____v1|
// |v3     v2|v3     v2|
// |         |         |
// |         |         |
// |    0    |    1    |
// |         |         |
// |v0_____v1|v0_____v1|
```

every patch has a colour. Patch 0, patch 1, patch 2 and patch 3. The vertices of that patch are the same of the patch colour. Then I change the vertices colours by averaging the colours with adjacent patches. So at first, I get the colour of patch 0 and 1, add them together then divide by 2, then I set this new colour to the vertex 1 of patch 0 and vertex 0 of patch 1.

However, I saw a paper where they get different results.

[image]

On this image, he sort of tried to explain how he got those values. But I didn't understand. He is doing something very similar from what I did, but I think he does get rid of match band effects.

I get results like this:

[image]

This is the results I get with my Radiosity rendering:

[image]

This is the results I get with my interpolation method:

[image]

It did got more smooth, but I still have huge mach band effects

Comment: "I saw a paper where they get different results." - can you give the name of the paper?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what the figure 8a is trying to accomplish, but your implementation sounds reasonable to me.

The artifacts you see are not a problem of you interpolation but due to the fact that you have a low-contrast color gradient on a flat surface.

If for example RGB color changes from (100,0,0) to (110,0,0) over 100 pixel, then every ten pixels you have change in color by 1 in the red channel. As your scene is very simple these edges extend over larger parts of the image. The human brain is very good at detecting them, so voila.

Probably the only way around would be to use a more complex scene, to use textures or to use a fragement-shader with some artificial small noise.